# JSP EL returning empty string

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a jsp page that used to work, and I'm not quite sure what happened.  I'm using Eclipse's jetty to power it.

As a test, this works:

```
<%=request.getParameter("abc")%>
```

so does this:

```
<%out.write(request.getParameter("abc"));%>
```

using EL though is just returning an empty string:

```
${abc}
```

As I say, I had been using this last method right along, and for some reason it's no longer working.  I've tried looking at other jsp pages I have that were working as well, and they are just returning empty for any parameters as well, despite them existing.

Comment: Did you try using ${param.abc}

Comment: That works.  However I'm even more confused as to how, or how request was working before.

Comment: Before, but before what?

Comment: Did you have changes in the source code?

Comment: Nope. Perhaps it didn't work, and I just hadn't noticed.  Not really sure.